# python: How to decrement and update values for a field in delimited text

Tags: python

I have a text file (bowtie alignment file) that looks like this:

```
read_1  +   345995|PACid:16033981   599 AGTAGTAATCAGTCACCCGCAAGGTAGACAAGG   qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq!!qqqqqqqqqq   0   
read_2  +   949205|PACid:16054220   338 TACCAGCACTAATGCACCGGATCCCATCAGATC   qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq!!q   0   31:A>T
read_3  +   932004|PACid:16034380   1226    GGCACCTTATGAGAAATCAAAGTTTTTGGGTTC   qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq!!qqqqqqqqqqqqq!!q   3
```

I want to subtract one from Column #4 (the position), and print each line with the updated value.

I can read the file, then separated the fields based on tab, and also identify Column #4 as `data[3]`, but then I am stuck with subtracting one from each value in Column #4 and printing all the fields in each line with updated value for Column #4.

How can I do this using Python?

I tried something like this:

```
in_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
out_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
for line in in_file: 
    data = line.rstrip().split('\t') 
    position = int(float(data[3]) -1)
```

but I am not sure about how to proceed with printing the lines with updated position.

Comment: With which part of the problem are you stuck? (Reading the file? Identifying the fourth column? Subtraction? Printing?)

Comment: Hey! I recognise that, it's part of my DNA sequence. Where did you get that from? Goldarned internet and it's lack of privacy! :-)

Comment: As a side note, is it necessary to use Python? Because this would be really easy with awk, something like `awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} NF > 0 {$4 -= 1; print}' <in.txt >out.txt`

Comment: @Johnsyweb, I can read the file, then separated the fields based on tab, and also identify the column 4 as data[3], but then I am stuck with subtracting one from each value in column 4 and printing all the fields in each line with updated value for column 4.

Comment: @  paxdiabl: the data is publicly available-from genbank :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), informing it your field delimiter is a tab:

```
from io import StringIO

indata = StringIO(u"""read_1    +   345995|PACid:16033981   599 AGTAGTAATCAGTCACCCGCAAGGTAGACAAGG   qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq!!qqqqqqqqqq   0
read_2  +   949205|PACid:16054220   338 TACCAGCACTAATGCACCGGATCCCATCAGATC   qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq!!q   0   31:A>T
read_3  +   932004|PACid:16034380   1226    GGCACCTTATGAGAAATCAAAGTTTTTGGGTTC   qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq!!qqqqqqqqqqqqq!!q   3
""")

# that StringIO stuff is just for testing, you should do
# with open('your_file_name', 'r') as indata:
# before the 'for' loop, and then indent the rest one level.

from csv import reader

for line in reader(indata, delimiter='\t'):
    if len(line) > 3:
        line[3] = str(int(line[3]) - 1)
    print '\t'.join(line)
```

Then just convert the position to a number, subtract one, convert it back, and print the line.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an error with the above code :         line[3] = str(int(line[3]) - 1)
IndexError: list index out of range. I need to print all fields in the original file, with column 4 updated. I tried to do something like this,                                                               in_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
out_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

for line in in_file:
    data = line.rstrip().split('\t')
    position = int(float(data[3]) -1, but I am not sure about how to proceed with printing the lines with updated position.

Comment: @psaima Then you've got lines with less than four rows. It works fine for the sample data. You can add an `if len(line) > 3:` test inside the `for` loop to filter out bad lines. I'll edit that in to my answer.

Comment: @psaima Basically your existing code is almost right, just change `position = int(float(data[3]) -1` to `data[3] = str(int(data[3]) - 1)`, then you can `print` it the way I did --- `print '\t'.join(data)`.